# Ring AlarmClock immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, alarm, android-alarms

Is there a way to immediately activate Android's AlarmClock? I'm trying with `AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM` along with the current hour and minute, but that will just set it to 23 hours and 59 minutes from now. 
Any help? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you would be better served explaining what the end result you want is. Is it simply displaying the alarm UI? The alarm tone?

The behavior you want is not possible. The end result still may be.

Comment: I basically want to bring up the fullscreen alarm that comes up when a normal alarm has been activated. It can be done with 1 minute delays, but not immediately?

Answer (score 0):

AlarmClock class is using to set up Alarm clock for the android, unfortunately you could not define seconds of the alarm and it is quite have to do this with AlarmClock to ring immediately.

This is a brief code sniper with 1 minute delay:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "New Alarm");
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 1);
startActivity(i);
```

To show alarm screens immediately:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now, but I want it to be immediate, not 1 minute.